# Объявление массива

Tags: c++, массивы, c++11, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Почему я могу объявить `a`, но не могу `b`?

```
std::array a = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::array<std::array> b = {{1,2,3,4,5}};
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что компилятор не знает, что `{{1,2,3,4,5}}` - это именно `std::array<std::array>>`. Вы пытаетесь уговорить компилятор вывести не просто параметр шаблона, но и шаблонный параметр параметра шаблона (если не запутался :))

Попробуйте так:

```
std::array a = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::array<std::array<int,5>,1> b = {{1,2,3,4,5}};
```

или так:

```
std::array b = {std::array{1,2,3,4,5}};
```

Comment: А в первом случае почему знает? Я хочу, чтобы можно добавить ещё элементов и не пересчитывать сколько их, как в `a`

Comment: Потому что `{1,2,3,4,5}` содержит этот размер и тип, так что с++17 позволяет вывести параметры шаблона из инициализации (в с++14 первая запись работать не будет).

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы выводился тип и для `b`? или так нельзя?

Comment: Я показал в обновленном ответе вариант - явно указать, что внутренний массив - это именно `std::array`. Тогда вы сможете добавлять, скажем, `std::array b = {std::array{1,2,3,4,5},std::array{6,7,8,9,10}};` - но следите за тем, чтоб, скажем, случайно количество элементов во вложенных массивах случайно не оказалось разным...

Comment: а без добавления внутренних `std::array` нельзя? Просто у меня есть таблица готовая огромная, хочеться без изменений её присвоить `b`

Comment: Если ну очень хочется, то 2*2 достигает и 5... Что вы хотите? Чтоб я переписал стандарт? А по делу - у меня регулярно бывают ситуации, когда пишется на коленке разовый преобразователь одного формата данных в другой. Тут вообще, как я понимаю, контекстно можно сыграть - заменить { на std::array{ и не мучиться... Уже давно бы сделали и забыли, чем искать какие-то пути полегче.

Comment: я хочу, чтобы обе строки вопроса работали без ошибок. Так можно?

Comment: Простите, вы соображаете, что спрашиваете? "А меня этот код не работает. Я хочу, чтоб он работал **именно так, как я написал**!" Ну перепишите компилятор...

Comment: То есть нельзя так сделать?

Comment: Динамические массивы вышли из моды? Мне кажется они вам как раз будут.

Answer (score 1):

C std::array так не получится, зато получится с std::vector

```
vector<vector<int>> b = { {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8} };
```

UPD: Без new и оборачивания каждой внутренней скобки в array:

```
//придётся посчитать сколько элементов в строке
std::size_t n = 5; // Все строки должны быть одинаковой длины
int m[][n] = { {1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9,10} };
```

Comment: А у вас получается то же самое, как если написать `array<array<int,N>,M>` - т.е. полностью определтитьтип без вывода из инициализатора.

Comment: Мне нужны массивы

Comment: Ну так vector и есть те же самые массивы

Comment: @BeaverFeller нет, вектор - динамическая память, а `std::array` - стек

Comment: Обновил ответ без использования new

Comment: @BeaverFeller ну так надо знать длину строк таким способом, а мне надо чтобы как в вопросе - без знания какой-либо длины

Comment: Ну если вы будете вставлять массив прямо в код, то тогда у вас уж точно будет возможность узнать длину строк, а если лень считать, то придётся делать как написал Harry, т.е. сделать замену всех всех { вставляемого массива на std::array{